# Django Remove all Empty Lines from Template Output

Tags: python, django

I'm rendering a Django template with lots of nested loops and if statements.  This causes a template output of approximately 30 000 lines.  Obviously I need to remove  those empty lines!

I have tried:

```
{% spaceless %}

{% endspaceless %}
```

However I get thrown an error when using it with 'if' statements in between:

> Invalid block tag on line 447: 'endspaceless', expected 'elif', 'else'
>   or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I have also tried:

```
outputStr = str(result._container[0],'utf-8')
outputStr2 = re.sub(r'^$\n', '', outputStr, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

with result being the HttpResponse object.  However the blank lines are not removed and I'm unsure of how to convert the string back to bytes.

Then the option exists to use middleware such as this post suggests:

[How to remove spaces and empty lines from HTML in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781379/how-to-remove-spaces-and-empty-lines-from-html-in-django)

That seems a bit dangerous to me.  SO would like to avoid that.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `django-htmlmin`

```
pip install django-htmlmin
```

> for a single view

Using the decorator
django-htmlmin also provides a decorator, that you can use only on views you want to minify the response:

```
from htmlmin.decorators import minified_response

@minified_response
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

> for all project

Using the middleware
All you need to do is add two middlewares to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and enable the HTML_MINIFY setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # other middleware classes
    'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
    'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',
)
```

Note that if you're using Django's caching middleware, MarkRequestMiddleware should go after FetchFromCacheMiddleware, and HtmlMinifyMiddleware should go after UpdateCacheMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
    # other middleware classes
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',
)
```

You can optionally specify the HTML_MINIFY setting:

```
HTML_MINIFY = True
```

The default value for the HTML_MINIFY setting is not DEBUG. You only need to set it to True if you want to minify your HTML code when DEBUG is enabled.

Reference: https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin

Answer (score 5):

I didn't like adding new dependency just for this. I choose a different approach using a custom template tag, `lineless` just a name.

It removes only empty lines. The lines with spaces or any characters detected by Python `strip()` function as white space.

### Full code

`templatetags/custom_filters.py`

```py
from django.template import Library,Node

register = Library()

@register.tag
def lineless(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endlineless',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return LinelessNode(nodelist)


class LinelessNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist

    def render(self, context):
        input_str = self.nodelist.render(context)
        output_str = ''
        for line in input_str.splitlines():
            if line.strip():
                output_str = '\n'.join((output_str, line))
        return output_str
```

### Use example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>{% load custom_filters %}{% lineless %}

...

</html>{% endlineless %}
```

Or if you want to keep HTML & Blocks syntax correct:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>{% load custom_filters %}{% lineless %}

...

{% endlineless %}
</html>
```

### Note

- Readable HTML is not a requirement for production, it just adds more stress on the server. So the best is to activate it only with debug mode.

Comment: This feels like a terrific solution. Will test and add more comment after some use.